# Is it feasible to have one docker image for an already existing application with multiple dependencies

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am new to Docker and want to learn the ropes with real-life challenges.

I have an application hosted on IIS and has dependencies over SQL Express and SOLR.

I want to understand the following:

1. Is it possible to have my whole set-up, including of enabling IIS,
   SQL, SOLR and my application in one single container?
2. If point 1 is feasible, how should I start with it?

Sorry if my questions are basics.

Comment: At the very very least, the database almost definitely needs to be in a separate container.  (You don’t want to delete the database every time you have a code change.)

Comment: @DavidMaze not really, you can have the actual data of the database in a volume that persists and the database software in the same container, it's just... sad to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is feasible, just not a good practice. You want to isolate the software stack to improve the mantainability (easier to deploy updates), modularity (you can reuse a certain component in a different project and even have multiple projects reusing the same image) and security (a software vulnerability in a component of the stack will hardly be able to reach a different component).

So, instead of putting all together into the same image, I do recommend using [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to have multiple images for each component of the stack (you can even pull generic, up-to-date images from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/)) and assemble them up from the Compose file, so with a single command you can fire up all the components needed for your application to work.

That being said, it is feasible to have all the stack together into the same Dockerfile, but it will be an important mess. You'll need a Dockerfile that installs all the software required, which will make it bulky and hard to mantain. If you're really up for this, you'll have to start from a basic OS image (maybe [Windows Server Core IIS](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore-iis)) and from there start installing all the other software manually. If there are Dockerfiles for the other components you need to install and they share the same base image or a compatible one, you can straight copy-paste the contents into your Dockerfile, at the cost of said mantainability.

Also, you should definitely use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) to keep your data safe, especially if you take this monolithic approach, since you risk losing data from the database otherwise.

TL;DR: yes, you can, but you really don't want to since there are much better alternatives that are almost as hard.